# VBA Code Should not Proceed Further Until Webpage is launched

Tags: vba, html

Do you have any alternative to the following code:

```
Do While IeNav.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
Loop
```

As this is catching, my vba code is moving ahead without the webpage launched completely which is leading to the run time errors. PLease help me if you have any suggestions

Comment: you could add more of your code to see other settings of your code.

Comment: What part of the page hasn't rendered when readystate = READYSTATE_COMPLETE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Application.Wait` in place of DoEvents.

```
Do While IeNav.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop
```

If you do go ahead and use Application.Wait you may wish [check the remarks on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851%28v=office.14%29.aspx) regarding it as it may disable some usage for the time it is running.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is helpful however we can not estimate the time right ?? So I would need something perfect where my code should not pass until and unless webpage launched....

Comment: It's inside the loop so every time the page is not ready it will wait another second before trying again. When the page is ready it will leave the loop, therefore I'd suggest one second would work well in this case.